# Rewrite ConcurrentHashMap compute() and computeIfPresent()

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

The implementation of ConcurrentHashMap is quite complex, as it is specifically designed to allow concurrent readability while minimizing update contention. At a very high level of abstraction, it is organized as a bucketed hash table.

One problem with ConcurrentHashMaps, in the context of mobile apps, are functions such as compute() and computeIfPresent() which require API 24 (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

I am wondering how I can satisfy lower level devices, how to rewrite compute() and computeIfPresent() to apply to devices API23 and less?

Here are some situations I am using these functions.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            scheduledTasks.compute(uid) { _, oldTask ->
                val newTask = ScheduledTask(uid, runnable, interval, null)
                if (oldTask != null) {
                    oldTask.cancel()
                    requiresRestart.set(oldTask.isScheduled)
                }
                newTask
            }
        } else {
            // TODO Need lower API implementation
        }
```

In the above example I am updating scheduledTasks which is a ConcurrentHashMap. Multiple scheduled tasks across several threads can be created.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return scheduledTasks.computeIfPresent(uid) { _, oldTask ->
                val future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                        oldTask.runnable, 0, oldTask.interval.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                ScheduledTask(oldTask.uid, oldTask.runnable, oldTask.interval, future)
            }
        } else {
            // TODO Need lower API implementation
            return null
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually have that enabled in my gradle already. But that doesn't make my code compatible for devices less than API 24. That is my question. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: But it does, though.  Read the docs: "the plugin extends support for using a number of Java 8 language APIs _without requiring a minimum API level for your app._"  It supports any API level.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, but this isn't for me. This is actually a SDK. The problem isn't on my end, it's Integrators who have lower requirements. Unless we force them to make these same updates, this isn't the solution I am seeking. I can rewrite the functionality of a compute() for example, which in general terms is just atomically updating the value, there is a check for if the remapping function throws an exception, the exception is re-thrown, and the current mapping is left unchanged, during computation, update process on the map from other threads is blocked, ect. I can imitate the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll only give the example for `computeIfPresent`, as `compute` is very similar, just more work.  This is in Java; it doesn't make a particular difference to convert to Kotlin.

```
 public <K, V> V computeIfPresent(
     ConcurrentMap<K, V> map, K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> f) {
   V currentValue = map.get(key);
   while (currentValue != null) {
     V nextValue = f.apply(key, currentValue);
     if (nextValue == null) {
       if (map.remove(key, currentValue)) {
         return currentValue;
       }
     } else if (map.replace(key, currentValue, nextValue)) {
       return currentValue;
     }
     currentValue = map.get(key);
   }
   return null;
 }
```

This version has the appropriate atomicity guarantees.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what I was looking for. There is an issue with "f.apply(key, currentValue)". The apply() is an API 24 function. I am trying to write code lower level than that.

Comment: Define your own interface and use that.  This is just an example.

Comment: I cannot call your function on lower end devices, for example, API 22 device due to the apply() is what I mean. Is there a way to rewrite the apply() function? All else works good. That apply() function is also in the original computeIfPresent, which is why calling that function also has the API 24 requirement.

Comment: Actually, I know how to rewrite so it works. It's just reassigning and updating the value. Cheers!